# PyCharm remote debugging about double SSH

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-debugging

Using PyCharm remote debugging is one of my favorite choices when doing deep learning jobs on Server platform. But recently I face a problem is that I have to first use SSH to login the platform then I will need another SSH to access the computing node. I may have to do this using my shell.

```
ssh myname@myip
ssh mynode
python myfile.py
```

Thus, usually when I use PyCharm. I can only do as the following:

```
ssh myname@myip
python myfile.py
```

My question is: how I can use PyCharm to double my SSH operation?

Comment: You need to use ProxyJump or ProxyCommand. Note: it's not supported on Windows.

Comment: Could you please provide some more specific details about that with PyCharm configurations? Or it will be published on server side or client side?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I use **MobaXterm** as the intermediate  jump tools.

1. Choose **Tunneling** toolbar, you will get a dialog like this [1st step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqHHY.png)
2. Click the **gear** in settings box,and then edit the **local port forwarding** like this [2nd step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGohc.png)
3. The final step, adding remote interpreter in pycharm:

   3.1. Choose **ssh interpreter**

   3.2. The **host** should be **localhost**, and **port** is the one mapped to your own PC. Then enter your **username** and follow the dialog.

   Here is the figure of [3rd step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCacu.png)